# SpriteKit What is a node?

Tags: sknode

I'm new to programming in Swift in general and I was reading up on SpriteKit.
I'm looking through a lot of tutorials and they keep talking about nodes.
The funny thing is, I can't seem to find what a node is....

Can anyone give me a good explanation of what a node is?
When I hear the term node, I think of the nodes in a Binary Search Tree but I have no idea what node means in SpriteKit

Thanks !

Comment: which tutorial did u refer ?? did u try it

Answer (score 0):

Here's the documentation definition from Apple

> SpriteKit implements content as a hierarchical tree structure of nodes. A node tree consists of a scene node as the root node and other nodes that provide content. Each frame of a scene is processed and rendered to a view. The scene executes actions and simulates physics, both of which change the contents of the tree. Then the scene is rendered efficiently using SpriteKit.

A node is just a unit / abstract data type with pointers.

> Nodes contain data and also may link to other nodes. Links between nodes are often implemented by pointers